# How to debug a simple database in C?

Tags: c, database, debugging, struct

This is a program in C that puts all the database(struct) to file and read that afterwards but when I executed it by this: (after compilation)

> a ab.txt w 1 abc abc@me.com

The program crashed and stopped working `<windows>`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h>

struct Rows{
int id;
int state;
char* name;
char* email;
};


struct database{
struct Rows rows[200];
};

struct connection{
FILE* fil;
struct database *db;
};
size_t dbsize = sizeof(struct database*);

void die(char* err){
if(errno)perror(err);
else fprintf(stderr,err);
exit(0);
}


struct connection fileopener(char* filename,char mode){
struct connection conn;
if(mode=='w')conn.fil=fopen(filename,"a+");
else conn.fil=fopen(filename,"r+");
return conn;
}

void writetof(struct connection conn){
int rc =fwrite(conn.db,dbsize,1,conn.fil);
if(rc!=1)die("cannot write");
rc = fflush(conn.fil);
if(rc==-1) die("cannot flush");
} 

void writetodb(struct connection conn,int id ,char*name,char* email){
if(conn.db->rows[id].state = =1)die("already written");
conn.db->rows[id].state=1;
conn.db->rows[id].id=id;
conn.db->rows[id].name = strdup(name);
conn.db->rows[id].email = strdup(email);
}

void delete(struct connection conn,int id){
conn.db->rows[id].state=0;
}

void readfrom(struct connection conn,int id){
if(conn.db->rows[id].state==0)die(" no record sorry");
else {
printf("id\tname\temail\n");
printf("%d\t%s\t%s\n", conn.db->rows[id].id,conn.db->rows[id].name,conn.db->rows[id].email);
}
}

void printall(struct connection conn){
int i =0;
printf("id\tname\\temail\n");
for(;i<200;i++){
if(conn.db->rows[i].state==1){
printf("%d\t%s\t%s\t",conn.db->rows[i].id,conn.db->rows[i].name,conn.db->rows[i].email);
}
}
if(i==0)die("no records");
}

void init(struct connection conn){
int i ;
for(i=0;i<200;i++){
conn.db->rows[i].id=i;
conn.db->rows[i].state=0;
}
} 

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
if(argc<3)die("need filename and mode");
char* filename = argv[1];
char mode = argv[2];
struct connection conn = fileopener(filename,mode);
init(conn);
int mid;
fread(conn.db,dbsize,1,conn.fil);
if(argc>3)mid = atoi(argv[3]);
switch(mode){
case 'w':
if(argc<6)die("need data to be written <id> <name> <email>");
writetodb(conn,mid,argv[4],argv[5]);
writetof(conn);
break;
case 'r':
if(argc<3)die("need id");
readfrom(conn,mid);
break;
case 'p':
printall(conn);
case 'd':
delete(conn,mid);
break;
default:
die("mode should be w , r , p d");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indent your code properly. Use some debugger like `gdb` to check for crash.

Comment: Posting on Stackoverflow should not be the first step in debugging (and not even the second, third, etc). Exhaust all  basic debugging techniques first. Namely using a debugger and/or debug print statements to trace the execution of your program.

Comment: `fread(conn.db,dbsize,1,conn.fil)`. Where do you allocate memory for `conn.db`? Looks like an unintialised pointer to me.

Comment: `fread(conn.db,dbsize,1,conn.fil)`  : meaningless.

Comment: sorry i will take care of that in the future and that fread is used because if the file consisted of the database than it will copied ... i think so

Comment: What do you mean by `<windows>`? Is that a code construct?

Comment: @Blade the general,It is to save the address held by the pointer to the file does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Problems I see:

**Failing to check the return value of `fopen`**

You have:

```
struct connection fileopener(char* filename,char mode){
   struct connection conn;
   if(mode=='w')conn.fil=fopen(filename,"a+");
   else conn.fil=fopen(filename,"r+");
   return conn;
}
```

I suggest adding a check there to deal with failure to open the file.

```
struct connection fileopener(char* filename,char mode){
   struct connection conn;
   if(mode=='w')conn.fil=fopen(filename,"a+");
   else conn.fil=fopen(filename,"r+");
   if ( conn.fil == NULL )
   {
      die("cannot open file");
   }
   return conn;
}
```

**Using uninitialized pointer**

You have

```
void init(struct connection conn){
   int i ;
   for(i=0;i<200;i++){
      conn.db->rows[i].id=i;
      conn.db->rows[i].state=0;
   }
}
```

At this point `conn.db` is not initialized. You need to allocate memory for it before you use it. Change it to:

```
void init(struct connection* conn){
   int i ;
   conn->db = malloc(sizeof(*(conn->db)));
   for(i=0;i<200;i++){
      conn->db->rows[i].id=i;
      conn->db->rows[i].state=0;
   }
}
```

I suggest changing the argument type to a pointer and allocating memory for it. Otherwise, memory allocated for `conn.db` will be only for a local copy of the object, not the object in `main`.

That implies changing the call to `init` in `main` to:

```
init(&conn);
```

Comment: i fund that there is a problem in `writetof()` in line `int rc =fwrite(conn.db,dbsize,1,conn.fil);`
because above that all works as i did some printfs but what??